# user specific mail sending in html and js

Tags: javascript, html

I have send subject and body along with mail id in html href tag
like this,
**href="mailto:a@a.comsubject=Your+tip+on+mailto+links&body=Thanks+for+this+tip"**
  now I want to create form in which user will fill data and after click on "send" button that data gets combine with body tag in href link.
so is it possible ?

Comment: I'd Google e.g. `html send form through email in javascript`

Comment: Post your code what you have done so far

Comment: @Pekka웃  yes I want the same but still whatever I have filled in input tab it's not reflecting on outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far what I have understood from your question is that you are willing to get the **href** attributes for submitting the form value. If it is in the same page along with the form then you can use [get attribute method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute)
for getting and using the values on your function. If it is on some other page then you muct send those attributes to the page where your form is.

If you provide your code sample then more specific things could be said.

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: It is not a good idea to use form tag to send information. Rather you can use hidden fields for sending those data.

Comment: you can check how to do it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto)

Comment: okey !! I have one more doubt that is when I click on send button outlook express gets opened, so in message body (in outlook) I want to display input fields (for that I want to use html tags) in which user can fill the data. so is that possible ? thanks for taking efforts for helping me :)

Comment: Here is exactly what you are looking for... [Insert HTML tag in outlook without being messed up](https://www.mapilab.com/blog/insert-html-into-outlook-email-message/)

Comment: please guide me "page can't display" message is getting on screen.

Comment: If you are using IE then visit [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/956196) to solve your issue. You can also visit [here](http://forums.timewarnercable.com/t5/Email/Page-Can-t-Display-message/td-p/72877) a similar problem like yours.

Comment: Was my comment about helpful about the first problem. I am not getting anything from you. :P

Comment: may be office blocking some site, I'll check it at home...after solving the problem I'll upvote you :p

Comment: thats fine..:) but atleast i have solved your first problem. That comment should be upvoted. :D

Comment: hahaha it's not solved I choose other option to solve the problem, that's why I started with the statement "I have one more doubt" :D :D :D just wait for the day i'll surely upvote you with satisfaction :p